# How do I create a table with the time field in the format HH:MM where HH IN [00, 23] and MM IN [00, 59]?

Tags: sql

my question is: how can I create  table with the time field in the format HH:MM where HH IN [00, 23] and MM IN [00, 59] and h_ini <= h_fin in SQL?

By now I have this:

```
CREATE TABLE X(
H_INI TO_CHAR(NUMBER(4), 'HH:MM')
H_FIN TO_CHAR(NUMBER(4), 'HH:MM')
CONSTRAINT EN_H_INI CHECK(H_INI BETWEEN);
```

I do not know how to do the check fot HH and MM. Thanks:)

Comment: Use the `time` data type - but not every DBMS supports it. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields. However, a time value consists of fields (hour, minute etc.)

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you could use a VARCHAR(5) for it.

Then check via a constraint if it's a valid time.
F.e. via a regex.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE X (
>    H_INI VARCHAR(5)
>  , CONSTRAINT EN_H_INI CHECK(REGEXP_LIKE(H_INI, '^([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$'))
> );
> ```

> ```
> insert into X (H_INI) values ('23:59');
> insert into X (H_INI) values (null);
> ```

> ```
> insert into X (H_INI) values ('24:00');
> ```
>
> ```
> ORA-02290: check constraint (EN_H_INI) violated
> ```

> ```
> select H_INI
> from X
> ```
>
> ```
> | H_INI |
> | :---- |
> | 23:59 |
> | null  |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f67b26a7349e7a1628e75c1d6cae01dc)*